# WebDriver - Testing Multiple Platforms

Tags: selenium, cucumber

I want to use Selenium Webdriver to test a web app using JUnit. I want to use the same tests cases to test different browsers; example: first I want to run all my scenarios on chrome and then I want to automatically run all my scenarios on Firefox.

What is the suggested method to do this?

Comment: The only way that comes to mind is by having multiple copies of the same scenario i.e. one saying "Given I am a Chrome user" and another saying "Given I am a Firefox user". I also considered the Examples table but that would require to duplicate outcomes for both platforms

Comment: That would be ideal but one of the drivers I need to test doesn't support grid :(

Comment: Could you not just create a different type of browser for each test run?  And have a rake task that ran your tests on each browser in turn?

Comment: @SiKing I managed to get the driver compatible with Selenium Grid, can you please elaborate on how to have the grid run on multiple browsers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I decided to use Parametrised JUnit tests, as a parameter I initialise the appropriate PageObject in the parameter list, see the example below:

```
@Parameters
        public static Collection<Object[]> data() {
            return Arrays.asList(new Object[][] {
                    { new ChromePageObject() },
                    { new FirefoxPageObject() }
            });
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    if(arg1 == "chrome"){ 
      _driver = new ChromeDriver();
    }
    if(arg1 == "firefox")
      _driver = new firefoxDriver();
    }
```